# How do I chain one promise to another?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use two promise libraries in the same chain, rp is request-promise and dc is my own that checks to see if dates are in order.

```
/*this works fine (checks if date are in correct order)*/
dc.checkIfDateIsAfter(departure_date,return_date)
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.log)

/*this also works fine (makes a post request)*/
rp(options)
.then(console.dir)
.catch(console.error)

/*This works up until the rp call, how do I write this chain?*/
 dc.checkIfDateIsAfter(departure_date,return_date)
.then(console.log).then(rp(options))
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.log);
```

Comment: You're calling `rp` _immediately_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises' `then` function works by taking in a *function*. In this code section:

```
dc.checkIfDateIsAfter(departure_date,return_date)
.then(console.log)
.then(rp(options))
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.log);
```

What you're doing with the second `then` call is passing in a function *that has already been called with some parameters*, and so what's actually being passed to the `then` function is the **result** of the `rp(options)`. You notice how all of the `console.log` are used without their usual parentheses? This is why.

The fix is to pass in a function with the data you want "bound" to it, but without calling the function yet. The way to do this in JavaScript would be:

```
dc.checkIfDateIsAfter(departure_date,return_date)
.then(console.log)
.then(rp.bind(null, options))
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.log);
```

The rp.bind() sort of "saves" the options to be used to later call the rp function. The reason the first argument is `null` is because that is the parameter used as the `this` variable inside of the function call, which we don't really need (hopefully).

Another fix would be to create a new anonymous function whose specific role is to call `rp` with `options`:

```
dc.checkIfDateIsAfter(departure_date,return_date)
.then(console.log)
.then(function() { return rp(options); })
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.log);
```

Comment: Mind blown. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.then` expect `function` as parameter, otherwise its ignored, as `rp(options);` seems to return `Promise`, it's resolved value is not in concern.

You should use a function to wrap it, and return the result from calling `rp(options)`.

It's also worth note that `console.log` returns `undefined`, if you're expecting the result from `checkIfDateIsAfter`, you should also wrap that, and return the result, so the value can pass to next then.

```
dc.checkIfDateIsAfter(departure_date,return_date)
.then(function(res) {
  console.log(res);
  // Pass the value which would be logged to next chain
  // if it'll be used later.
  return res;
}).then(function(res) {
  // if the rp has anything to do with the value.
  rp(options);
})
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 dc.checkIfDateIsAfter(departure_date,return_date)
  .then(console.log)
  .then(function(){ return rp(options);})
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.log);
```

Comment: This works. Annoying that I have to put in the function(){return...}.

It would have been so nice without it. Why must there be a function return?